# SFTP connection issues

Tags: sftp

I just setup a new debian sftp server in order to provide access to multiple CHROOTed users.
While the first account I added works just fine, the second one disconects right after authentication.

sftp -v output:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2416, received 1376 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 279797.8, received 159355.1
debug1: Exit status -1
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

and the user's config:

```
Match group joseph
        ChrootDirectory /backups/joseph
        x11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

rw permissions for the CHROOTed folder are a+rw and is owned by root.

Any ideas?

PS - I should also add that "Subsystem sftp internal-sftp" is there.

Comment: [I wonder if this is related](http://serverfault.com/q/384676/118258).

Comment: Have you checked server-side log?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl could you point me to it?
I tried looking for it but it was not mentioned anywhere when looked for its location in google.

Comment: @HopelessN00b My sftp -v -v -v looks quite different.

Comment: Aaaaand the problem is back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I made some kind of mistake while i created the users and groups following [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/) guide to the letter.

How is actually worked for me:

```
$useradd <user>
$usermod -d /<folder> -s /bin/false <user>
$chmod 744 /<folder>
```

- Gave the user permission to read/write on his own folder.
- Allowed  to connect using the ssh/sfpt protocols
- Added this for each user in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

> Match group 
>   ChrootDirectory /folder
>   x11Forwarding no
>   AllowTcpForwarding no
>   ForceCommand internal-sftp