# how to check that the shell is not set to either /sbin/nologin or /bin/false

Tags: login

Trying to follow this solution: https://serverfault.com/a/384811

But couldn't follow these final steps:
"also, check that the shell is not set to either /sbin/nologin or /bin/false, which would also block login, even with a successful authentication."

I'm on lubuntu recovery shell. How should I proceed? I have rudimentary knowledge on all this. TY

Comment: Just check in `/etc/passwd` that you don't have `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` defined in the last field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "also, check that the shell is not set to either /sbin/nologin or
>   /bin/false, which would also block login, even with a successful
>   authentication."

In the link you provided, the above refers to `/etc/passwd` file.

The `/etc/passwd` file format is as follow :

> 1. Username: It is used when user logs in. It should be between 1 and
>      32 characters in length.
> 2. Password: An x character indicates that encrypted password is stored
>      in /etc/shadow file.
> 3. User ID (UID): Each user must be assigned a user ID (UID). UID 0
>      (zero) is reserved for root and UIDs 1-99 are reserved for other
>      predefined accounts. Further UID 100-999 are reserved by system for
>      administrative and system accounts/groups.
> 4. Group ID (GID): The primary group ID (stored in /etc/group file)
> 5. User ID Info: The comment field. It allow you to add extra
>          information about the users such as user's full name, phone number
>          etc. This field use by finger command.
> 6. Home directory: The absolute path to the directory the user will be
>      in when they log in. If this directory does not exists then users
>      directory becomes /
> 7. Command/shell: The absolute path of a command or shell (/bin/bash).
>      Typically, this is a shell. Please note that it does not have to be
>      a shell.

Here, you are interested in the last parameter : `Command/shell`

[In case you could find this interesting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false), here are the difference between `/sbin/nologin` and `/bin/false` :

> When /sbin/nologin is set as the shell, if user with that shell logs
>   in, they'll get a polite message saying 'This account is currently not
>   available.'. This message can be changed with the file
>   /etc/nologin.txt.
>
> /bin/false is just a binary that immediately exits, returning false,
>   when its called, so when someone who has false as shell logs in,
>   they're immediately logged out when false exits.

---

So, basically, just check in file `/etc/passwd` that you don't have `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` defined in the last field for the user you need.

(well, not sure why i wrote such an answer as my initial comment should be enough, but that is...)